# How to ensure that apt upgrade doesn't change grub.cfg or restore it afterwards?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, apt, grub2

My computer normally runs Windows, but is configured to dual boot Windows/Ubuntu 18.04. I also have MS Hyper-V configured to be able to boot the same Ubuntu install as a VM, since the two OS's are on separate disks. GRUB is the boot manager (or GRUB2, whatever comes normally with this version of Ubuntu).

Normally, I boot Windows, and run Ubuntu in the VM when I need to. When I run apt upgrade, it will sometimes muck with the grub config, and since it doesn't see the Windows disk, it doesn't put in an entry to boot Windows. This means that the next time the system boots, it boots into Ubuntu, and I have to run Grub Customizer to restore that entry in the menu.

So, is it possible to STOP apt from automatically running roughshod over my grub.cfg? Or, failing that, does apt upgrade create a backup of grub.cfg that I could somehow restore? OR, failing both of those, what's the best way to manually create my own backup of the grub.cfg file so I can restore it as necessary. My understanding is that there's also normally a "human readable" version of this file as well, so any backup/restore scheme should keep the two files in sync. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What you should really do is learn how to configure GRUB properly. You should never modify `grub.cfg` directly

Comment: I'm not modifying grub.cfg directly. I am using Grub Customizer.

Comment: @tastewar A comment from the well-experienced heyyenma ihttps://askubuntu.com/users/4272/heynnema n the Comments section of my answer below suggests some instability can appear in GRUB as a result of using GRUB Customizer. I don't know, for I don't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy your /boot/grub/grub.cfg beforehand to grub.bak, grub.before, grub.alt, or something else.  It's a text file, not a binary, and there's [more about it here](https://opensource.com/article/17/3/introduction-grub2-configuration-linux).

After the upgrade, compare the current grub.cfg to the copy with the [comparison tool of your choice](https://www.tecmint.com/best-linux-file-diff-tools-comparison/), and if need be, copy from the copy back to grub.cfg.

If you want to also save each of the constituent files which are concatenated to make the grub.cfg, tar up the contents of /etc/grub.d plus /boot/grub/grub.cfg , then untar into /temp and compare with the tool of your choice after you've made a significant change and need to check.

Comment: I'm aware it's a text file but as your link documents, "It is generated by the grub2-mkconfig program using a set of primary configuration files" so I'd want those backed up as well. Hoping there's a tool for this...

Comment: Note if using grub customizer it creates its own versions of grub's scripts, they have proxy in their names. You normally should just be editing 40_custom with Windows entry and backing that up. Only a new/reinstall of grub would then overwrite the grub configuration files & revert to defaults. Normal `sudo update-grub` just runs scripts & creates new /boot/grub/grub.cfg

Comment: @oldfred Had a problem resolving a dependency for grub-customizer yesterday, so not recommending it TFN. Notes not immediately at hand for specifics.

Comment: I agree with oldfred and fkraiem... learn to use GRUB properly... edit the files in /etc/grub.d and /etc/default.

Comment: I understand that the OP is not directly editing grub.cfg... but if they properly configured files in /etc/grub.d... instead of using that nasty Grub Customizer, they'd have a more stable, more recreatable system... esp after kernel updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
sudo cp -a /boot/grub/grub{.cfg,.bak} ; sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade ; sudo cp -a /boot/grub/grub{.bak,.cfg} ; sudo rm -f /boot/grub/grub.bak
```

BUT... changes to `grub.cfg` may not be the source of your problem(s). Chances are things might be messed up by `update-initramfs` ([What does update-initramfs do?](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2356604))

If this is the case backing up `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` before and restoring after `apt upgrade` will do little to fix your problems. Your best bet will be to boot with a previous kernel version under the grub sub-menu **Advanced Options for Ubuntu**.

The other thing to consider we often run `sudo update-grub` manually to get new parameters such as `nomodeset` updated from `/etc/default/grub` into `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` so we would just be doing the work manually that we perceive `apt upgrade` is doing automatically.

Comment: I suppose so, but it does seem that it's just a menu option that gets deleted. I imagine this is because it can't access the device that is being referred to, but I don't know.

Comment: I can only speculate on what you are asking now. Perhaps a new question of your specific problem is needed.